# Is it possible to find lines with multiple occurences of the same word with grep?

Tags: grep

Is it possible to write a (one line) grep expression to find lines which contain three occurrences of the same word? Note that we don't know the word a priori. The following snippet catches most cases:

```
$ grep -E '(\w+)[[:space:]]+\1[[:space:]]+\1' test_data.txt
```

However, this does not catch the following positive example:

lunch **supper** **supper** **supper** lunch

Also note that we are only looking for complete words, not simply character repetitions. So an example of a negative example would be:

**he** plucked t**he** flowers t**he**re

EDIT (thanks to @lev-levitsky):

The positive example above is actually caught, but the following is not:

**lunch** **lunch** supper supper **lunch**

Comment: But it *does* catch the example with supper. Should it match three words separated by other words?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Changed it to 'lunch lunch supper supper lunch', which doesn't get caught.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
grep -E "[[:<:]](\w+)[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]\1[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]\1[[:>:]]" testfile
```

for instance:

```
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ cat testfile
how is summer summer summer ha ha
this summer is a hot summer of summers yes it is
summer summer summer
there is only one summer in this sentence
summer appears as the first and last summer words in this summer
the summertime is always in summer, one of several summers
the summer of which we speak is summery but is a real summer summer, yes
this also works with cats, since there are three cats in these cats, ha!
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$ grep -E "[[:<:]](\w+)[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]\1[[:>:]].*[[:<:]]\1[[:>:]]" testfile
how is summer summer summer ha ha
summer summer summer
summer appears as the first and last summer words in this summer
the summer of which we speak is summery but is a real summer summer, yes
this also works with cats, since there are three cats in these cats, ha!
paul@horus:~/src/sandbox$
```

`[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` match the null string at the beginning and end of a word, respectively, so you can use them to determine word boundaries without having to assume the words are separated by whitespace, rather than by punctuation characters, etc.

Comment: Found a slightly more compact notation for your solution: grep -E '\<(\w+)\>.*\<\1\>.*\<\1\>' testfile

Answer (score 0):

This is not `grep` nor `regex`, but it may work:

```
awk -F"[,. \t]*" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (++a[$i]==3) {printf "%s ",$i;f=1}} if (f) print "";f=0;delete a}' file
```

It counts the word on each line, and prints the word on the line if there is three or more found of it.

Comment: In this case it doesn't work:

$ echo 'supper supper supper.' | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if (++a[$i]==3) {printf "%s ",$i;f=1}} if (f) print "";f=0;delete a}'

Comment: @user313967 Fixed by adding Field Separator `-F"[,. \t]*"`  PS this you must take in account in an `regex` too.